# Can we call EJB from workitemhandler of JBPM?? Can anyone pls give some reference site or example?

Tags: java, jbpm

I am trying to call EJB from JBPM workflow . I tried using workitemhandler. I am getting null pointer exception. I am not able to find any example of JBPM workflow calling EJB
I have tried the below:

```
1. workitem
import org.drools.core.process.core.datatype.impl.type.StringDataType;
[
  [
    "name" : "EjbTask",
    "parameters" : [
      "Message1" : new StringDataType()
     ],
    "displayName" : "EjbTask",
    "icon" : "icons/world.png"
  ]
]
2. workitemhandler 
public class EjbTask implements WorkItemHandler{
    @EJB
    IDlTestEjb testEjb;
   public void abortWorkItem(WorkItem arg0, WorkItemManager arg1) {
    }
    public void executeWorkItem(WorkItem workItem, WorkItemManager manager) {
        try {         
          testEjb.getId("123");          
          manager.completeWorkItem(workItem.getId(), null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

3.I have added the project with the interface IDlTestEjb as dependency to JBPM project

I am getting null pointer exception in the line where testEjb is being called.

Comment: show us what you've tried

Comment: Can we call EJB from workitemhandler? Because I am new to both EJB and JBPM. So not very sure whether am doing the right thing

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use an EJB from a WorkItemHandler. Your EjbTask class, which implements the WorkItemHandler should be annotated with `@javax.inject.Named` and `@javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped`. I have those annotations and the rest of my code is basically the same. Having that, I am able to use the EJB in the executeWorkItem() method.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for the response.. i tried by using those annotations but still facing the same issue. can you pls attach your example? Thanks in advance.